# Не применяются стили для input[type="email"]

Tags: html, css

```
.class_email{
border:3px solid #061e37;
border-radius:8px;
width:45%;
margin-right:5%;
height:50px;
}
.class_email input [type="email"]{
outline:none;
border:none;
height:100%;
font-size:30px;
padding-left:10px;
width:95%;
font-family:"S-B";
color:#061e37;
 }
<div class="class_email">
                    <input type="email" class="email_input" placeholder="Email">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`input [type="email"]` пишется слитно, не через пробел `input[type="email"]`

```
input[type="email"]{
  outline:none;
  border:none;
  height:100%;
  font-size:30px;
  padding-left:10px;
  width:95%;
  font-family:"S-B";
  color:#061e37;
 }
```

Comment: Cпасибо большое!Я думал нет разницы!Теперь буду знать!А то уже не знал что тут не так.